# Generating a new binomial variable from existing variables

Tags: r, categorical-data

Suppose I have the following data:

```
Var1 = (1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
Var2 = (1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
Var3 = (0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0)
```

Using `if`/`else` syntax in R, I need to create new `Var4`, so that

```
if var1=1 & var2=1 & var3=1 then var4=1
if var1=0 & var2=0 & var3=0 then var4=0
if var1=1 & var2=0 & var3=0 the var4=1 and so on.
```

Basically, `var4=0` when all three variables=0 only.

Answer (score 2):

We can `cbind` the 'var' vectors, get the `rowSums` and check if it is greater than 0, coerce the logical to binary with `+`

```
+(rowSums(cbind(Var1, Var2, Var3)) > 0)
```

---

Or use `|`

```
as.integer(Var1|Var2|Var3)
```