# Creating new variable using loops in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, binary, statistics

I have a two binomial variables and I need to create a new variable (var3) such that

```
if var1=0 and var2=0 then var3=0
if var1=1 and var2=1 then var3=1
if var1=1 and var2=0 then var3=1
if var1=0 and var2=1 then var3=1

Let var1=c(1,0,1,0,1,1)
    var2=c(0,0,1,1,0,1)
```

I know I can use as.integer(Var1|Var2|Var3) and pmax(Var1, Var2), but how to do it using loops in R.

Comment: Can you accept the answers to your previous questions if those have been solved ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop? In general loops are slow in R, the solutions you have listed are faster

Comment: @Beata How is this fundamentally different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895792/generating-a-new-binomial-variable-from-existing-variables)? It seems to me that all of your recent questions are very similar in nature. Also please consider Ronak's comment and accept answers to your previous questions by setting the green check mark next to the answer that addressed your question best. This is the equivalent of saying "thank you" to others for helping you for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if index of var1 and var2 are same you can use following code :

```
var1=c(1,0,1,0,1,1)
var2=c(0,0,1,1,0,1)
var3 = NULL
for (i in 1:length(var1)) {
if(var1[i] == 0 & var2[i] == 0){
a = 1
}
else
  a = 0
var3 = rbind(var3,a)
}
var3
```

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio)
[loops](/questions/tagged/loops)